# Gmail keyboard shortcut to go into reply text area

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

I use GMail keyboard shortcuts a lot.  When I reply (<kbd>R</kbd>), but I meant to reply-all, I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd>, to switch the reply to all.

But then, I have to either use the mouse, or tab a bunch of times to get back into the area where I write my response.

Is there a shortcut or hack that jumps right to this text area?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>esc</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>esc</kbd> : gets you out of edit mode

<kbd>o</kbd> : opens the document [basically returns the document to 'unedit' state.

<kbd>a</kbd> : reply all